# Passing a C++ object with an Objective-C (Cocoa) event (performSelector)

Tags: c++, iphone, object

How to pass a C++ object with the performSelector method? This method only allows you to pass 'objc_object*' objects, I can't cast them. I could build a wrapper, but I don't know the overall superclass for all C++ objects, so I don't know how I could build a generic wrapper (I don't want specific knowledge about the object in the wrapper)..

Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try just using +[NSValue valueWithPointer:].

Comment: You may wish to create and delete the NSValue with the object it refers to for increased performance.

Comment: Superb, this works in conjunction with [myNSValue pointerValue] :)