# Handle Cocoa setAction message in Objective-C++

Tags: c++, cocoa, qt, objective-c++

How do you handle the `setAction` message in Objective-C++? (*Not Objective-C.*)

For example, suppose I have:

**my_class.mm**

```
NSSegmentedControl *segmented = [[NSSegmentedControl alloc] init];
[segmented setSegmentCount:5];
// etc.
[segmented setAction:???];
```

Application: I am programming in Qt (C++) and need a wrapper around some Cocoa widgets I want to use directly. I am inheriting from `QMacCocoaViewContainer` but can't figure out how to handle the "clicks" of the `NSSegmentedControl` I am wrapping. Eventually this will emit a standard Qt signal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`action` is just a selector - it is used in tandem with `target`. so write an objc method for target+action which calls through or does what you really want. `actions`' arguments are the sender, but you can omit that if you don't need it. the sender will be whatever is sending the message (e.g. the control). it's no different in ObjC++ - this has to be wrapped in an objc method because the target must be an objc object.

so it would look like this:

```
obj.action = @selector(pressDoStuff:);
```

and the method is:

```
- (void)pressDoStuff:(id)sender
```

Comment: What @Justin said. I end up writing lots of little proxy Objective C classes that have Objective C methods that call C++ methods.

Comment: This is giving me "expected unqualified-id before '-' token" compile error.

Comment: @Dave there's nothing wrong with the code I posted. have you put it in the right place? and is your source compiled as ObjC or ObjC++?

Answer (score 1):

*@Justin has the right answer; I'll accept it, but also include the final solution in case it helps others. The trick is you need a proxy class, as @smparkes noted.*

Ignoring the `.h` files for brevity:

**mac_control.mm**

```
MacControl::MacControl(QWidget *parent) : QMacCocoaViewContainer(NULL, parent) {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  NSSegmentedControl *segmented = [[NSSegmentedControl alloc] init];
  // Set up NSSegmentedControl...

  // The proxy class marshalls between Objective-C and C++.
  proxy_ = [[MacControlProxy alloc] init];
  [proxy_ setTarget:this];
  [segmented setTarget:proxy_];
  [segmented setAction:@selector(handleToggle:)];

  setCocoaView(segmented);
  [segmented release];

  [pool release];
}

MacControl::~MacControl() {
  delete proxy_;
}

void MacControl::TriggerAction(int index) {
  // Trigger the action in Qt/C++.
}
```

**mac_control_proxy.mm**

```
@implementation MacControlProxy

- (id)init {
  [super init];
  target_ = NULL;
  return self;
}

-(void) handleToggle: (id)sender {
  if (target_) {
    target_->TriggerAction([sender selectedSegment]);
  }
}

-(void) setTarget: (MacToolbarButtonControlImpl*)target {
  target_ = target;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm following up on Dave Mateer's answer (which was super helpful!).

I was having issues setting the C++ target (from within a objective-C++ class) and used [NSValue valueWithPointer:theTargetCxxClass] to pass the target to the Proxy.mm class.

So, inside of my Objective-C++ class, rather than doing this:

```
[proxy_ setTarget:this];
```

I did this:

```
[proxy_ setTarget:[NSValue valueWithPointer:this]];
```

or

```
[proxy_ setTarget:[NSValue valueWithPointer:ptrToMyCxxObject]];
```

And doing this got rid of an error about passing a C++ class (which does not extend type "id") to the Objective-C++ proxy class.

Inside of the proxy class, you then need to use NSValue's pointerValue method and then cast back to the C++ class in order to send a message to it.

```
-(void) myButtonAction: (id)sender {
  ((MyCxxClass*)[target pointerValue])->someMethodInMyCxxClass();
}
```

I first was alerted to the "valueWithPointer" trick in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928152/passing-a-c-object-with-an-objective-c-cocoa-event-performselector).